# JavaScript track click on div exclude inner id?

Tags: javascript

I've got the following JavaScript code to track clicks on a div:

```
    var anchor = document.getElementById('clickMe');
    if (anchor.addEventListener) {
        anchor.addEventListener('click', clickHandlerOpen, false);
    } else if (anchor.attachEvent) {
        anchor.attachEvent('onclick', function () {
            return clickHandlerOpen.apply(anchor, [window.event])
        });
    }
```

My html looks like this:

```
<div id="clickMe">
     <div id="someContent"><p>hello</p></div>
     <div id="closeMe">X</div>
</div>
```

How can i exclude the id `closeMe` from the above click handler? I want the `closeMe` to have its own.

Please note that i do not want to use `jQuery`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the `target.id` of the clicked element inside your function:

```
clickHandlerOpen(event) {
    //Satisfy IE8
    event = event || window.event; // get window.event if argument is falsy (in IE)

    // get srcElement if target is falsy (IE)
    var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;

    if (targetElement.id == 'closeMe') return false;
    //your code here
}
```